# How to have two different tables for authentication in Laravel? (JWT)

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-5.3

I have a mobile application(mobile_users) and a backend to manage the system(system_users) i want to manage them in **separate tables** so basically to communicate with the mobile application i'm trying to use an api with `JWT` enabled and for the backend i'm using default auth method in laravel.

My problem is when i try to change the auth table for JWT it keeps on accessing the system_users table, even though the documentation says you can change the default **User model path** i tried changing but no luck,

Please help me with this,

I'm using https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth this library for JWT,

My Database Structure will be,

```
mobile_users_table = authentication using JWT

system_users_table = default laravel auth
```

**api.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/


Route::post('auth', 'Api\v1\AuthController@authenticate');
Route::get('auth/me', 'Api\v1\AuthController@getAuthenticatedUser');

Route::get('validate', function () {
    return "cool";
})->middleware('jwt.auth');
```

**AppUser.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AppUser extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**AuthController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v1;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }


        public function getAuthenticatedUser()
        {
                try {

                        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
                        }

                } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

                } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

                } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

                        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

                }

                // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
                return response()->json(compact('user'));
        }
}
```

**jwt.php**

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Model namespace
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Specify the full namespace to your User model.
    | e.g. 'Acme\Entities\User'
    |
    */

    'user' => 'App\AppUser',
```

Comment: @goto please have a look

Answer (score 0):

For different authentication, there are library already exist. check this, it will solve your problem https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

Comment: you mean it's not possible without a library?..or have any other method?

Comment: Without a library, you can do it. Laravel has a concept [Guard](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-guards), it will handle user according to the role.